# Partitioning a MySQL table based on a column value.

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I want to partition a table in MySQL while preserving the table's structure.

I have a column, `'Year'`, based on which I want to split up the table into different tables for each year respectively. The new tables will have names like `'table_2012'`, `'table_2013'` and so on. The resultant tables need to have all the fields exactly as in the source table.

I have tried the following two pieces of SQL script with no success:

1.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE all_data_table
> (   column1 int default NULL,
>     column2 varchar(30) default NULL,
>     column3 date default NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  
> PARTITION BY RANGE ((year)) 
> (
>     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
>     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) , PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ,
>     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2013), PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
> );
> ```

2.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE all_data_table PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (`year`)  (
>     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2011),
>     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012),
>     PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
>     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
> );
> ```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but seeing as it comes up highly ranked in partitioning searches, I figured I'd give some additional details for people who might hit this page.  What you are talking about in having a `table_2012` and `table_2013` is not "MySQL Partitioning" but "Manual Partitioning".

Partitioning means that you have one "logical table" with a single table name, which--behind the scenes--is divided among multiple files.  When you have millions to billions of rows, over years, but typically you are only searching a single month, partitioning by Year/Month can have a great performance benefit because MySQL only has to search against the file that contains the Year/Month that you are searching for...so long as you include the partition key in your WHERE.

When you create multiple tables like `table_2012` and `table_2013`, you are MANUALLY partitioning the tables, which you don't do with the MySQL PARTITION configuration.  To manually partition the tables, during 2012, you put all data into the 2012 table.  When you hit 2013, you start putting all the data into the 2013 table.  You have to make sure to create the table before you hit 2013 or it won't have any place to go.  Then, when you query across the years (e.g. from Nov 2012 - Jan 2013), you have to do a UNION between table_2012 and table_2013.

```
SELECT * FROM table_2012 WHERE #...
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_2013 WHERE #...
```

With partitioning, this manual work is not necessary.  You do the initial setup of the partitions, then you treat is as a single table.  No unions required, no checking the date before you insert, etc.  This makes life much easier.  MySQL handles figuring out what tables it needs to query.  However, you MUST make sure to query against the Year column or it will have to scan ALL files.  E.g. `SELECT * FROM all_data_table WHERE Month=12` will scan all partitions for Month=12.  To ensure you are only scanning the partition files that you need to scan, you want to make sure to include the partition column in every query that you can.

Possible negatives to partitioning...if you have billions of rows and you do an ALTER TABLE on the table to--say--add a column...it's going to have to update every row taking a VERY long time. At the company I currently work for, the boss doesn't think it's worth the time it takes to update the billion rows historically when we are adding a new column for going forward...so this is one of the reasons we do manual partitioning instead of letting MySQL do it.

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert at partitioning...so if I'm wrong in any of this, please let me know and I'll fix the incorrect parts.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you want to create many tables from one big table.

I think you should try to create views instead. 
Since from what I look around about partitioning, it actually partitions the physical storage of that table and then store them separately. But if you see from the top perspective you will see them as a single table.